# A way to reset program on cmd?

Tags: java, cmd

I wrote a simlpe dice game and would like to know a way to reset the program after typing something like "Reset". I use cmd to run my programs. There is no graphics included in any of my programs whatsoever.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random; 


public class Dice
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
 String personPlay; //User's play 
 String computerPlay = ""; //Computer's play 
 int computerInt; //Randomly generated number used to determine computer's play 
 String response; 


 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 Random generator = new Random();

 System.out.println("Let's play some dice!");

 //Generate computer's play 
 computerInt = generator.nextInt(6)+1;

 //Translate computer's randomly generated play to 
 //string using if statements 

 if (computerInt == 1) 
    computerPlay = "1"; 
 else if (computerInt == 2) 
    computerPlay = "2"; 
 else if (computerInt == 3) 
    computerPlay = "3";     
 else if (computerInt == 4) 
    computerPlay = "4";
 else if (computerInt == 5) 
    computerPlay = "5";
 else if (computerInt == 6) 
    computerPlay = "6";  

 //Get player's play from input   
 System.out.println("Choose a number between 1 and 6."); 

 personPlay = scan.next();

 //Print computer's play 
 System.out.println("The dice rolled " + computerPlay);
 //See if you won. 
 if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay)) 
    System.out.println("You won!"); 
 else System.out.println("You lost!");
}
}
```

Comment: Aside... Those if statements can simply be `computerPlay = String.valueOf(computerInt);`

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? Your code only runs once, no variables are saved, therefore everything is already "reset" when you run again.

Comment: What about adding a kind of do-while-loop. do-while ensures that the game is played at least once. Inside the loop you can ask the user if he wants to play again and check this input as part of the while-condition.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of that?  I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a do-while to restart a game in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317447/using-a-do-while-to-restart-a-game-in-java)

Comment: @SteveTwist I think there is already an example online at SO. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317447/using-a-do-while-to-restart-a-game-in-java).

Comment: i assume the 'while' part is at the end (i may be wrong) but where do i put the 'do' part in

Comment: A [`do-while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) is one thing.

Comment: @SteveTwist No, the `do` is at the top, `while` at the bottom, ie. `do {} while ()`. As I said, the idea is that this kind of loop is executed at least once. In contrast to this, the body of the while-loop may never be executed (if the condition does not hold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I don't like giving full answers, but there are some improvements I wanted to show and just listing them would be a lot of work as well.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random; 


public class Dice
{ 
    private static void play(Scanner scan, Random generator)
    {
        int computersPlay, usersPlay;

        System.out.println("Let's play some dice!");
        computersPlay = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;

        System.out.print("Give a number:");
        usersPlay = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("The dice rolled %d\n", computerPlay);

        if (computersPlay == usersPlay) {
            System.out.println("You win !");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You lose!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner scan      = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random  generator = new Random();

        do {
            play(scan, generator);
            System.out.println("If you want to continue type:'Reset'");
        } while(scan.next().equals("Reset");
    }
}
```

**Changes** moving the play to a different method to keep oversight, using the Scanners nextInt method to obtain a number directly and compare that instead, and the `do {} while();` statement to let it repeat an arbitrary amount of times (given that you type reset)

Answer (score 1):

You should use an infinite loop and get input from user, check if user entered "RESET", if so roll the dice again or do whatever you're doing now.
If he entered a phrase like "EXIT" infinite loop ends or your program ends.

Answer (score 0):

By "reset" I assume you meant "repeat"? Use a `while` loop.

Also, no real need to store String values other than capture what the user entered.

```
public class DiceGuess {

    // Global variables for this class
    static Random generator = new Random();
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Let's play some dice!");

        // Initialize some variables
        int computerInt;
        String response;

        while (true) { // Play forever
            computerInt = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("Choose a number between 1 and 6. ('quit' to stop playing)");
            response = scan.nextLine();

            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) break; // Stop the game

            try {
                System.out.println("The dice rolled " + computerInt);

                if (Integer.parseInt(response) == computerInt) {
                    System.out.println("You won!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You lost!");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("That wasn't a number!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```